# Get data from WMS-like page into QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I would need to use data from this page: http://dosoremi.hu/int_agyag_0_30.html. However, changing windows all the time isn't too effective. Do you think I can get the same images into my QGIS maps?

Comment: You could make a screenshot and the georeference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data in the map is coming from a WMS server.

Just add the URL to QGIS using the "Add WMS/WMTS Layer button".

URL:

```
https://maps.rissac.hu:6443/arcgis/services/dosoremi_web_mercator/MapServer/WMSServer?LAYERS=4&PROJECTION=EPSG%3A3857&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&VERSION=1.1.1
```

Comment: The URL to add to QGIS should be: https://maps.rissac.hu:6443/arcgis/services/dosoremi_web_mercator/MapServer/WMSServer?